# Entire monitor image "shaking" up and down, excessive IPS monitor burn in?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 installation on a standalone machine which is causing my [ASUS IPS monitor](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/VS239HP/specifications/) to obtain a [very noticeable ghost image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VfzQ.jpg) after a few minutes of use.

The machine is connected via a HDMI cable from the on-board Intel graphics, the ghosting of the desktop is seen after plugging the monitor into a different source. The ghosting does not go away even after a power cycle of the monitor.

This is a crypto-currency mining rig which also has 5 Nvidia graphics cards installed. As a result I am using the Nvidia v384 driver with a custom xorg configuration (generated by `nvidia-xconfig` and stored in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`).

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 384.98  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-02)  Thu Oct 26 15:56:05 PDT 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "layout"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen2"
    Screen      4  "Screen4" RightOf "Screen3"
    Inactive       "intel"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "keyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor4"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device4"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:7:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen4"
    Device         "Device4"
    Monitor        "Monitor4"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

---

I think the main cause of the problem is a constant "shaking" of the entire image drawn on the monitor. Its almost as if each frame on the monitor is drawn +1 then -1 pixels from "center" (each successive image is drawn 1 horizontal pixel up or down). I tried to take a video of this but it draws much faster than my phone can capture. When using TeamViewer this effect is not apparent at all.

I would have to image this is an issue with the configuration file not properly defining "what" the monitor is and how to draw on it, but I am not sure how to figure out if this is the issue or not. My other thought is that the Nvidia driver is "being mean" to the on-board Intel video output.

**Any idea what could be the cause of the screen shaking, and if the shaking is the root cause of the ghosting/burn-in?**

I can provide any necessary command outputs needed.

Comment: One thought is the cable itself going from the computer to monitor.  Mine was doing something similar and I found that the cable was laying across power cables causing the ghosting to happen.  It remained in multiple OSes, etc.  Make sure your cable is good and not next to anything that could cause interference.

Comment: Its 25 feet long, running over all sorts of other wires, and one end is very janky. I'll try a different one, I'm skeptical that it's the issue though. But it does knock out the only hardware cause I could imagine.

Comment: Tried it with a cable I tested on my desktop, same issues outlined above persist.